# THREE.WebGLRenderer: Unknown uniform type: 1009

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I'm using THREE.js r73, and I'm trying to make a particle system using `THREE.BufferGeometery` to hold the vertices and `THREE.ShaderMaterial` to add functionality to them. For some reason, I'm getting the error above. Here is my code (using Typescript). The error is occurring at the line `gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );` (The last one in the fragment shader).

```
this.particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud(
    this.particles,
    new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
            texture: wTex
        },
        vertexShader: `
            attribute vec3 color;
            attribute float size;

            varying vec3 vColor;
            varying vec2 vUv;

            void main() {
                vUv = uv;
                vColor = color; // set color associated to vertex; use later in fragment shader
                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
                gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
            }
        `,
        fragmentShader: `
            uniform sampler2D texture;

            varying vec3 vColor; // colors associated to vertices; assigned by vertex shader
            varying vec2 vUv;

            void main() {
                // calculates a color for the particle
                gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 1.0 );
                // sets particle texture to desired color
                gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
            }
        `
    })
);
```

The code was adapted from some examples I found online, but I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not constructing the uniform correctly. It should be...

```
uniforms: {
    texture: { type: 't', value: wTex }
}
```